# Searching a hash in table, using AR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I trying added hash object to column in my table.But I can not make the correct database query that would find value.

in **model.rb**

```
  serialize :options, Hash
```

`options` attribute

```
 options: {:price=>"20000", :room=>"1", :area=>"40", :floor=>"3", :metro=>"Parnas", :district=>"North-West"},
```

How make the correct database query that would find value?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialised fields are just YAML (by default) strings in the DB. So, you cannot search by it in regular way. What you can do are:

1. Select required DB records and search in them.

```rb
def relevant? opts
  opts.price == 2000 && opts.room == 1
end

Model.where(...).select { |m| relevant? m.options }
```

2. Convert your search options to YAML and search by the field as string. This will not work well, because it requires all fields from hash to be defined.

```rb
Model.where('options = ?', {price: 123, room: 1, ...}.to_yaml)
```

3. Use DB's pattern matching operators, for example, `LIKE`.

```rb
Model.where('options LIKE ? AND options LIKE ?', 'price: 2000', 'room: 4')
```

All this ways are limited and are not optimal in any sense. I suggest you to do not use serialisation on fields, that you want to query by.